# How to calculate minimum/maximum bandwidth for users of a home network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bandwidth, tv

I am using the TP-Link Bandwidth Control feature to limit speeds of various users over a 10mbps total bandwidth. Since I use IPTV, so I basically want 2 of the Smart TVs to be given priority so they are able to use at-least 8mbps whenever they need it (not simultaneously of course). Any other user for the time being should not exceed 2mbps at least when the Television is running. As per my understanding, I did the following:

TV Users

```
Min. Ingress Bandwidth: 4mbps
Max. Ingress Bandwidth: 9.5mbps
```

Other Users

```
Min. Ingress Bandwidth: 150kbps
Max. Ingress Bandwidth: 8.5mbps
```

Firstly, using the IP range feature, TP-Link assigns a total bandwidth limit to all IPs within the range, and not each IP so I am forced to create the rules per single IPs.

Second, now let's say TV starts downloading a video at 8mbps, would another user downloading at the same time be able to exceed 2mbps and decrease TV's bandwidth as a result or would TV still be given priority? If not, then how can I set it so that TV's bandwidth is always given priority as per demand?

Comment: What's the tp-link model number? Qos does per device priority. Limiting bandwidth per IP is not the same thing.

Comment: WR-941ND, the feature is same over all devices I guess.

Comment: https://www.tp-link.com/fr-be/faq-194.html

Comment: @Tim_Stewart yeah my router allows bandwidth limiting per IP only, not the device priority. So I was interested to know how would 2 users simultaneously using the bandwidth get affected?

Comment: I cant write a full post at the moment. But maybe someone else can give you a step by step as an answer.

Comment: The device that is set with the higher bandwidth will get priority in the case of overload

Comment: Okay. I’ve already tried the link. That’s good for a start, but it doesn’t actually explain the mechanism behind it or how would other users be impacted.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like the easiest:

```
TV1 ingress min:8m  max:0
TV2 ingress min:8m  max:0
```

Other hosts have no ingress min and will have lower priority, so the TVs will choke out your other hosts if for any reason the TVs together are using more than your uplink's current speed.

To give other hosts some bandwidth up front you could do this:

```
Others ingress min:1m  max:0
TV1 ingress min:8m  max:0
TV2 ingress min:8m  max:0
```

Now if the TVs are using more than your current uplink all hosts will still share the first 1m and the TVs will get the rest equally.

Keep in mind that your uplink speed will vary.  You may be paying for 10m, but normally you pay for the uplink max, not the min.

Setting max to 0 should default to no throttling, if it gives an error, set it as high as you can.

Comment: I gave that a thought but I would only be able to do it for a single IP (single TV), adding another rule like that throws an error as it doesn’t satisfy.

Comment: I see, I don't think I understood your question.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: I see your answer. This way the total bandwidth becomes 17mb ingress while I have a 10mbps connection. So it doesn’t justify it. But I get the point. Thanks. Did it for the IP range of both TVs together. I have a WR-941ND TP LINK